# Удаленное монтирование linux

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

Ситуация следующая: на одной машине монтируется флешка, на второй, удаленно, монтируется точка монтирования в которую смонтирована эта флешка. При размонтировании флешки на первой машине, на второй все данные все еще доступны, как я понимаю из кэша. Вопрос: как на второй машине хотя бы отлавливать тот факт что это размонтиоование произошло?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем из кеша. Линукс немного оптимизирует монтирование и вместо монтирования папки на удаленную систему монтирует туда саму флешку.

монтируйте папку на уровень выше. Тоесть флешку монтируете в /mnt/data а по сети отправляйте папку /mnt/

Comment: При монтировании на уровень выше директория в которой должны находиться данные с флешки пуста

Comment: тогда давайте в вопросе напишем как монтируется всё

Comment: Так как вы и сказали, флешку смонтировал в /mnt/data, по сети смонтировал /mnt, каталог /data в точке монтирования пустой. /mnt расшарена по сети (rw, insecure, no_root_squash, nohide, sync)

Comment: @ENTERF34R Попробуйте поиграться с crossmnt и no_subtree_check вместо nohide.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло crossmnt